# mongo db replication of collection to avoid lack of transactions

Tags: mongodb

I am having a db with a collections cA, cB and cC. I need to update the db each 5 minutes in a transactional way (cB is a n-m relation of cA and cC). Since it does not seem to be easy to emulate [transactions with mongo](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/), I though I could create snapshots (db.cA.copyTo("cA_snapshot")) of cA, cB and cC before starting the upload process and flip the reading queries on the snapshot while doing the inserts. Unfortunately, the collections size sum up to more than 8Gb and doing the collection.copyTo seems to take way too long.

So, is there a way to achieve this using journaling? Let's say I take the cost to create the snapshot of the collections once at startup. Afterwhile, could I replay the journaling items of cA on cA_snapshot manually?

thanks

Comment: MongoDB has no notion of snapshots.

Comment: by snapshot, I mean copying a collection : db.cA.copyTo("cA_snapshot")

Comment: Sounds like you want a RDBMS. You can do a snapshot query of the collections which could be saved while the process is done: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/#cursor.snapshot but this won't work with sharding other than that all I can recommend is to not upload 8GB of data regularly.

Comment: once the initial upload of 8GB is done, the further delta updates will typically be pretty limited. That is why I wanted to explore the idea to apply the journaling items of a collection over its "snapshot" version. This would typically be pretty fast compare to copying again the entire collection. I could then always have a readonly collection for the reading queries while saving in "write-only" collections without needing to care about transactions.

Comment: Use RDBMS when transactions are a must. MongoDB does not fit for everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to lock all updates to all three collections while you're updating the "join table", you could implement this with application-level locking.

Short version: you create a 'locks' collection.  Every client must acquire a "write lock" before updating any one of the three collections cA, cB, or cC.  It does so by updating a document in the 'locks' collection.  When you're ready to perform your batch update, you acquire the "write lock", perform the update, and release the lock.

Here is some simple example code that implements locking.  Note that there are several limitations to this code:

- There is no deadlock detection or prevention
- There is no lock timeout
- Attempting to re-lock a locked resource will always fail, even if the lock was previously acquired successfully

Fixing these limitations is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
XDB = db.mylocks;
/*
 * Set up the locking collection
 */
function setup_locking( res_name ) {
    var doc = { _id: res_name, state: "UNLOCKED", locker: null }; 
    // upsert to create document if it does not exist
    XDB.update( {id: res_name}, doc, true ); 
}

/*
 * Lock the resource named 'res_name' by process named 'proc' 
 *
 * Returns 'true' if resource was acquired, 'false' if it was not acquired
 */
function lockit( res_name, proc ) {
    /*
     * 1) Change state to LOCKED if & only if it was previously UNLOCKED
     */
    ret = XDB.findAndModify( {
            query: { _id:res_name, state:"UNLOCKED" } , 
            update: {"$set": { state:"LOCKED", locker: proc } },
            fields: { state:1, locker:1 },
            new: true
            }
        );
    /*
     * Return 'true' if this process acquired this resource
     */
    if ( ret && (ret.state == "LOCKED") && (ret.locker == proc) )return true;

    /*
     * 2) Failed to acquire this resource
     */
    return false;
}

/*
 *  Unlock the resource named 'res_name' previously held by 'proc'
 */
function unlockit( res_name, proc ) {
    // Unlock resource if this process had previously acquired it
    XDB.findAndModify( {
        query: { _id:res_name, locker: proc, state:"LOCKED" } , 
        update: {"$set": { state:"UNLOCKED", locker: null } },
        }
    );
}

/*
 * Check to see if resource 'res_name' is currently held by 'proc'
 */
function has_lock( res_name, proc ) {
    res = XDB.findOne({_id: res_name, locker:proc} );
    if (res == null) return false;
    return true;
}

XDB.drop();
setup_locking('collectionA');

result = lockit( 'collectionA', 'app1');
print("1: result =", result);

result = lockit( 'collectionA', 'app2');
print("2: result =", result);

result = lockit( 'collectionA', 'app1');
print("3a: result =", result);
result = has_lock( 'collectionA', 'app1');
print("3b: result =", result);
result = has_lock( 'collectionA', 'app2');
print("3c: result =", result);

unlockit( 'collectionA', 'app1');

result = lockit( 'collectionA', 'app2');
print("4: result =", result);
```